# Keyframed UV map not exporting in .dae?

Tags: animation, uv, collada, keyframes

I've made an oversized UV texture and keyframed the mesh face position on the UV map using AnimAll in order to change the image during an animation. Rendering the animation confirms the texture change works.

However, when after exporting to .dae the texture stays the same throughout. Is there a step I've missed or is this a limitation of the file format?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Blenders Collada exporter doesn't support Key framed UV's, also not sure if any other applications support exporting them.