# How to import uv animation from blender to unity?

Tags: animation, uv, unity

I'm animation uvmap in blender just fine using animall adon. When I import it into unity it totally ignores my animation.

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think this is possible at all on Unity, not in the way Blender allows it with AnimAll (very quick search brings solutions based on scripting, in Unity).

In any case, there is for sure absolutely no standard way to directly export UVMap animation from Blender, FBX does not support such feature afaik, and it’s one of the most advanced and best supported exchange format (Collada does not support this either, see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18926/keyframed-uv-map-not-exporting-in-dae)…).